# Issues with new Pixel 3 connecting to car

Tags: usb

So I've just switched back from IOS to Android and picked up a Pixel 3 XL with the 1-day sale. I tried setting up Android Auto though but I can't get it to work properly. I can connect and add my car (2017 Kia Niro), but after I try to select the Android Auto icon on the head unit it crashed and keeps flashing "Phone is not responding" and "Reading USB" over and over. On the phone, it still says connected to the car and shows the green notification bar suggesting Google Maps is in use. 
I've tried using an older version of AA, but it gives an error unless I update. If I try to connect, not press the icon on the head unit and start playing Spotify, I get 1-2 seconds of audio through the car but then it crashes again. One time I got as far as launching and selecting the navigation tab until it crashed. I've briefly talked to Google support and they requested a bug report which I've sent. I also tried updating to the Q beta to see if that made any changes. I've used 5 different USB cables with no luck.

I didn't have any issues with Apple Carplay, and I also tried a very old Samsung phone (micro-USB) successfully so it shouldn't be the car causing the issue. Does anyone have any tips on what I should look at? I've done a factory reset, cleared all cars, toggled the AA setting on the head unit but nothing makes any difference. I'm pretty reliant on this functionality, so if it doesn't work I probably will be switching back to my iPhone. I hope this is fine being on superuser, apologies if it shouldn't.

Comment: "_it shouldn't be the car causing the issue_" ... I wouldn't be so sure - when did you last update the head unit's firmware?

Comment: I have never, I searched for that and it doesn't appear KIA posts firmware updates any longer that I can tell. I can contact the dealer to check though. Wouldn't it working with the Samsung and Carplay also working suggest that shouldn't be the case?

Comment: Apple CarPlay is irelevant to Android Auto... older Android Auto devices (i.e: your old Samsung phone) may not use some of the newer features that the Pixel 3 supports... call in to a Kia dealership and whine at them? :-)

Comment: I'll see if I can schedule an appointment to find out if there are any firmware updates to it then. Thanks!

Comment: ...or find out who actually made the unit & see if they do firmware updates. Pioneer manage to trickle out about one a year for mine.

Comment: Well, turns out it was the cable. This was 4 old supposedly good cables from a few years ago, along with a new one from Best Buy. Picked up a new Insignia USB C cable where the reviews mentioned success with AA and it is working. Bit of a headache but good news.